# Which meaning does "Mad" have in the title "Mad Max"?

Tags: mad-max-fury-road

It might well be the fact that I come from a non-English speaking background, so please bare with me on this one. However, it makes me wonder, what meaning does "Mad" carry in the title of Mad Max: Fury Road? Based on Google's built-in dictionary, first meaning is "Insane or ill" yet Max doesn't look like one. Does it just mean "angry"?